# How handle an element of elements having same class name using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="user" class="user">akhilreddy</div>
<div id="user" class="user">subodh</div>
```

I many of elements but am showing only two, when ever I click on div I want text inside that div to be diplayed in alert box.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.user', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/RWeEa/**

You should also remove the duplicate IDs.

Comment: its working , yeah I removed will duplicate IDs have any effect on jquery functionality

Comment: @akhil Well, if you tried to select by ID, it won't only select the first element in the DOM with that ID, which may not be what you wanted. Having duplicate IDs means your HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

**first your ID should always be unique...**.. so change it..

secondly you can use `.click()` event , `this` reference and `text()` to get the text inside the div

```
 $('.user').click(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
 });
```

and if incase you are adding you element dynamically use `on` delegated event

```
 $(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.user',function(){
     alert($(this).text());
});
});
```

however it is recommended to delegate it to the closest static parent container that is present in the document rather than document itself

Comment: its not working actually iam placing those elements dynamically through jquery which will be replaced periodically after every 20 sec

Comment: the `on` should work then.. but make sure you keep it inside document.ready

Answer (score 4):

First of all

1) you have assigned duplicate id's  here  `id="user"`

please change your id's

```
<div id="user1" class="user">akhilreddy</div>
<div id="user2" class="user">subodh</div>
```

And then select the same class selector like `$('.user')`

You have to use On() if its dynamically added.

```
  $(document).on('click','.user',function(){
        alert($(this).text());
     });
```

Comment: its not working actually iam placing those elements dynamically through jquery which will be replaced periodically after every 20 sec

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".user").click(function(){
 // Do something
});
```

Answer (score 2):

using javscript

```
    <div id="user" class="user" onlick="alert(this.innerHTML)">akhilreddy</div>
    <div id="use1r" class="user" onlick="alert(this.innerHTML)">subodh</div>
```

using jquery

```
   $(".user").click(function(){

           alert($(this).text();

     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use same id for multiple divs. Ids must be `unique`.But you can apply same class to multiple divs.

```
<div id="user" class="user">akhilreddy</div>
<div id="use1r" class="user">subodh</div>

$('.user').click(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

'THIS' will reference the object that was clicked on:

```
$(this).
```

so, your code will be:

```
$('.user').click(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
});
```

where the

```
$('.user').
```

is selecting the divs with CLASS user.
As for the ID: you should never have identical ID's in a webpage!